# Android how to change views?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost, viewflipper

Basically I need some suggestions which is the best way to switch views in my situation. My Application has 5 different tabs. In every single tab I'm using activity manager to start as many activities that I need inside this tab. Now I have a little problem. In one of the tabs I need to create something like three different tabs. In second tabs I used 3 buttons, which switch the views via viewflipper. But now I have like 2 or 3 views inside every new tab (or button) which I need to switch. I did it with viewflipper but it's actually not what I want, because I want to use back button to switch between views.

Example:

```
MAIN TAB BAR :      ONE   TWO   THREE   FOUR   FIVE
SECOND TAB BAR INSIDE TAB THREE / OR JUST THREE BUTTONS : TAB-A   TAB-B   TAB-C

IN TAB-A I have only one view.
IN TAB-B I have 2 views. View 1 is a listView and onItemClick switch view 2.

IN TAB-C I have same scenario like in TAB-B.
P.S.  View 1 and View 2 directly can change to TAB-C.And I need to be able to send data between the views/activities.
```

Any suggestions how to do that? `ViewFlipper` or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use activities inside the tab THREE and create three buttons which starts new activity.And you can use ViewFlipper inside these activities to change the views,or viewswticher.It depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the onBackPressed in your activity to change the default behaviour of the back button

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()